# Using database name before table name in QSQLITE C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

I am using c++ QSQLDatabase (SQLITE driver) to interact with an sqlite3 database. The c++ code uses queries that have the database's name before the table name like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM database_name.table_name ...
```

But the query is rejected with an error:

> no such table : database_name.table_name

No way to change the query formats, is there any way in QSQLDatabase / SQLITE to make these kind of queries valid (without changing the queries)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

`database_name` is what SQLite calls a *schema name*. It starts with two - `main`, which is the originally opened database, and `temp`, where temporary tables, indexes, etc. are stored. You can't change the initial database being called `main`, but you can [`ATTACH`](https://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) new databases with arbitrary names (And possibly using a throw away [in-memory database or unnamed temporary db](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) as the initial one if you're only going to use fully qualified `schema-name.table-name` notation):

```sql
ATTACH 'another_database.db' AS database_name;
SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name;
```